# How to split sentences into sentence Id, words and labels with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, named-entity-recognition

I want to convert my pandas data frame into the format which could be used in NER models.

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

````
```
Sentence_id    Sentence                                                       labels
1              Did not  enjoy the new Windows 8 and touchscreen functions.    Windows 8
1              Did not  enjoy the new Windows 8 and touchscreen functions.    touchscreen functions
```
````

Is it possible to convert it into following format？

````
```
Sentence_id    words          labels                                                       
1              Did            O
1              not            O
1              enjoy          O
1              the            O
1              new            O
1              Windows        B
1              8              I
1              and            O
1              touchscreen    B
1              functions      I
1              .              O
```
````

The first word in labels should be labeled as 'B'(Beginning), the following words in labels should be labeled as 'I'(Inside). Other words and punctuations should be labeled as O(Outside).

Answer (score 0):

The solution a bit long. But you could do it using `df.iterrows()`.

```
import string

ids = df.Sentence_id.unique().tolist()     ## Assuming name of your dataframe is df
sentences = df.Sentence.unique().tolist()
labels = df.labels.unique().tolist()

def get_label(word, labels):
  if word == labels[0]:
    return 'B'
  elif word in labels and word!= labels[0]:
    return 'I'
  else:
    return 'O'

data = {}
exclude = set(string.punctuation)
for _, row in df.iterrows():
  words = ''.join(ch for ch in row['Sentence'] if ch not in exclude).split()
  puncts = ''.join(ch for ch in row['Sentence'] if ch in exclude).split()
  labels = row['labels'].split()
  for word in words: 
    if word in data:
      if word in labels:
        data[word][1] =  get_label(word, labels)
    else:
      data[word] = [row['Sentence_id'], get_label(word, labels)]
    for punct in puncts:
      data[punct] = [row['Sentence_id'],'O']

## Processing the dictionary to input into dataframe
ids = []
words = []
labels = []
for key, val in data.items():
  words.append(key)
  ids.append(data[key][0])
  labels.append(data[key][1])
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'Sentence_id':ids, 'words':words, 'labels':labels})
new_df

    Sentence_id words   labels
0   1           Did     O
1   1           .       O
2   1           not     O
3   1           enjoy   O
4   1           the     O
5   1           new     O
6   1           Windows B
7   1           8       I
8   1           and     O
9   1       touchscreen B
10  1         functions I
```

Comment: Sure, happy to help! Do let me know if it worked or needs some changes?